# Regex to remove

Tags: java, regex

Need regex to remove \" and '

```
 String date="\"CCB \\\"E Safety\\\" Internet Banking security components 3.0.7.0\"'Configuration & \\\"Service Tool v3.02.00'"
```

Reuslt String : CCB E Safety Internet Banking security components 3.0.7.0. Configuration & Service Tool v3.02.00

Im using this

```
System.out.println(date.replaceAll("[\\W+]", " ").replaceAll("\\s+", " "));
```

But it removes dot also

CCB E Safety Internet Banking security components 3 0 7 0 Configuration Service Tool v3 02 00

Comment: `date.replaceAll("\\s|\\\"|\\|'", " ")`?

Comment: @Lino Just `(')|(\\")` should work aswell, right?

Comment: You need `date.replaceAll("[\"'\\\\]", " ").replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").trim()`

Comment: @RickvanOsta I've edited the comment, I kept the \\ though, because OP has some of those in his code

Comment: @Lino I see that, but the single backslash wasn't part of the question, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = date.replaceAll("[\\\\\"'\\s]+", " ").trim();
```

**Result**

```
CCB E Safety Internet Banking security components 3.0.7.0 Configuration & Service Tool v3.02.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex!

The characters you want to remove can be removed without using regex, and it's a whole lot easier to read:

```
data = data.replace("\"", " ").replace("'", " ").trim();
```

---

In case you are wondering, `replace()` still replaces *all* occurrences, but the search parameter is just plain text, whereas `replaceAll()` uses a regex search parameter.